# How to adjust this script to use Glob instead of 1 file

Tags: php, thumbnails, glob

I have created this script based on reading other posts on StackOverflow. The script creates a thumbnail from the original image and adds it to a folder. The source images are located on my local server so Glob would work however I am not sure how to adjust this script so that it will run this function on all files in a folder (Glob). I realize it may be memory intensive but I only need to do it a few times on several folders and I'll be done with it.

Just in case you are questioning the reason I have included $height2, it is a little hack I came up with where we create the thumbnail while maintaining the aspect ratio then only save the top 250px so that the thumb is 250 x 250 but not distorted (stretched). It works great.

I just need to adjust to do a batch of all images in the source folder.

Any help would be great.  Please keep in mind that I am a front end developer (html and css) and not great at PHP.  This script alone took me forever to make work lol.

If anyone can help me adjust it for a full folder, that would be great.

```
foreach(glob('SourceFolder/*.jpg', GLOB_NOSORT) as $url); {

Thumbnail ($url, "DestinationFolder/*.jpg");

function Thumbnail($url, $filename, $width = 250, $height = true, $height2 = 250) {

// download and create gd image
$image = ImageCreateFromString(file_get_contents($url));

// calculate resized ratio
// Note: if $height is set to TRUE then we automatically calculate the height based on the ratio
$height = $height === true ? (ImageSY($image) * $width / ImageSX($image)) : $height;

// create image 
$output = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height2);
ImageCopyResampled($output, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, ImageSX($image), ImageSY($image));

// save image
ImageJPEG($output, $filename, 100); 
} 
}
```

Comment: There are examples on php.net for the `glob()` function that you can consult http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: I read examples and have just updated my code to "try" to apply it but it doesn't work.

Comment: Place `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script(s). Any errors from it?

Comment: I have added that and still no error is thrown.

Comment: The manual's example I thought you would have based yourself on, is the one about the `foreach`. Have you tried that instead, and/or in conjunction with the `for` loop? Something like `foreach(directories as directory) { glob this directory }`.

Comment: Yeah I have tried that. Honestly I'm totally lost at this point. As I had mentioned, I am more of front end coder and PHP is all new to me. I was able to get my script generating the thumbs, I just can't get this Glob to work for a batch. It's a little over my head and I only need to run it on a bunch of folders 1 time and be done with using it. I was hoping someone would help me get my code corrected so I can learn what I did wrong.

Comment: Ok, I have adjusted it again. There is something that I am doing wrong on the top 3 or 4 lines. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to adjust the code on my own after reading the online PHP manual.

The final code:

```
foreach (glob("SourceFolder/*.jpg") as $url) {

$destdir = "Destination/" . basename($url, null);

$width = 250;
$height = true;

 // download and create gd image
 $image = ImageCreateFromString(file_get_contents($url));

 // calculate resized ratio
 // Note: if $height is set to TRUE then we automatically calculate the height based on the ratio
 $height = $height === true ? (ImageSY($image) * $width / ImageSX($image)) : $height;

 // create image 
 $output = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);

 ImageCopyResampled($output, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, ImageSX($image), ImageSY($image));

 // save image
 ImageJPEG($output, $destdir, 100); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses opendir and readdir. I have found that this approach can 
handle folders with more files.

```
// Set desired height and width
$desiredWidth = 250;
$desiredHeight = true;
// Set source and destination folders
$srcFolder = "SourceFolder";
$destFolder = "Destination";
// This is more memory efficient than using glob()
$dh = opendir($srcFolder);
if ( ! $dh ) {
    die('Unable to open folder ' . $srcFolder);
}
while($filename = readdir($dh) ) {
    // only process jpg files.
    if ( preg_match('/.jpg$/', $filename) ) {
        $inputFile = sprintf('%s/%s', $srcFolder, $filename);
        $outputFile = sprintf('%s/%s', $destFolder, $filename);
        echo "file: $filename\n";
        echo "input: $inputFile\n";
        echo "output: $outputFile\n";
        $inputImage = @ImageCreateFromJpeg($inputFile);
        if ( $inputImage ) {
            // calculate resized ratio
            // Note: if $height is set to TRUE then we automatically calculate the height based on the ratio
            $height = $desiredHeight === true ? (ImageSY($inputImage) * $desiredWidth / ImageSX($inputImage)) : $desiredHeight;

            // create image 
            $outputImage = ImageCreateTrueColor($desiredWidth, $height);

            ImageCopyResampled($outputImage, $inputImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desiredWidth, $height, ImageSX($inputImage), ImageSY($inputImage));

            // save image
            ImageJPEG($outputImage, $outputFile, 100);
            ImageDestroy($inputImage);
            ImageDestroy($outputImage);
        } else {
            echo "Could not process file\n";
        }

    }
}
closedir($dh);
```